# git p4 sync only labels

Tags: git, label, perforce, git-p4

I am migrating a repo from Perforce to Git. I have already migrated all branches of interest. Now I am looking for  migrating all perforce labels as git tags.

I am running below command

> git-p4.py sync //depot/path/... --import-labels --verbose

This is not able to fetch all labels, saying it could not find git commit for changelist. If I run this with @all , its able to get the labels. Only concern is it will take more time.

Is there any option to import just labels, I am not keen for revisions. Thanks !

Comment: Did you find out how to Sync from Perforce to git just the files in labels?

Comment: it shall work with @all option, git-p4.py sync //depot/path/...@all --import-labels --verbose